# Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

i'm using react native with regex

if i use my code

this error occured

Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

I want to put an empty value like ' ' in the match if any character other than a number and decimal point is included in my regular expression. If you put "123abc" in the value variable, match returns "123", but if you put "acv" in the value constant, the above error occurs. In this case, how can I put an empty string into the match without generating an error?

```
 const regex = /\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/;

const value = "abd"
const [match] = regex.exec(value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `||` operator. in case `exec` return `null` it will default to empty string `''`.

```js
function getStrings(value) {
  const regex = /\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/;
  const [match] = [regex.exec(value) || ''];
  if(Array.isArray(match))
    return match[0]
  return match
}

console.log(getStrings("abd"))
console.log(getStrings("123abd"))
```

Comment: i tried your code but if value is "123" is comes out  Array.
how can i get just "123"? not array value